# Digital Signature/Receipt Workflow

Tags: workflow, designer

Within SharePoint Designer, I'm trying to create a workflow where when an asset (list item) is assigned to a user, it sends them an email where they have to accept ownership of this item. So at the moment I have two lists:

- Asset List Loan
- Tracker List

Adding an item (new loan) to the Loan Tracker and assigning a user to that should send them an email asking them to accept ownership of this. This would then mark that task as completed and that would be the end of the workflow. I've managed to get the email to send, however it only sends them a link to the status of the task and doesn't ask for approval. I'm very new to this so please bear with me!